# Postgresql jdbc driver vs EDB driver

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, enterprisedb, jdbc-postgres

What's difference between [Postgresql driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) and EnterpriseDB driver for Postgresql.
It seems like the former doesn't support procedures and the later supports it.
Anybody messed with executing callable statement with both the drivers ?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just searched for an answer to this old question... Best i could find was this:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/11.0.1/JDBC_Guide_11.0.1/EDB_Postgres_Advanced_Server_JDBC_Connector_Guide.1.30.html#

There ist also a (kind of) compatibility matrix:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/11.0.1/JDBC_Guide_11.0.1/EDB_Postgres_Advanced_Server_JDBC_Connector_Guide.1.09.html#